# Open Content Modal of Content Builder from Custom Block Widget

Tags: content-builder, modal, widget

I created a custom Block Widget using SDK: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk

Now I need to select the file from Content Builder (just like in Image Block)

Is it possible to open Content Modal within Custom Block Widget?[image]
I did not find such an opportunity in this BlockSDK